# android partial fragment -> swipe to see whole fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to do something like what the new google map on android does, if you type in an address, tap the marker, it'll show you a partial detailed view :
http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/new-maps-for-android.jpg

And then when you do a swipe up motion on the partial detailed view it becomes a whole view: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4x5My_0Cv1A/Ud02RfShHmI/AAAAAAABLBM/PqSywEyJx4A/s640/google-maps-android-3.jpg
 but you can still see part of the map. Thanks so much! I understand how google map works, and how to add the listener for on tap events, but I just don't know how to display the partial view and then swipe to get the whole view. Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know how to accomplish that as well!